# What would cause network traffic to spike in evenly distributed spurts?

Tags: networking, router, lan, pfsense, wan

This happens periodically, and I am looking into ways to monitor network traffic more closely, but it looks like my WAN2 (in) traffic bounces in almost perfect intervals, and at the same peak usage. Is this normal behavior, or should this be something I should look into right away?

Screenshot:

[image]

Measured in Mb/s

Comment: Spikey usage; router needs a firmware update, things like that.

Comment: I wish you'd included the time interval on that graph or in the text of your question. That could be a good clue.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an email client set to check for new messages every N minutes. Or anything periodically checking in with a server.

I doubt it's anything to worry about, but it should be easy to find if you want to put your mind at ease.